# jQuery dialog - a unique dialog gets duplicated on an ajax site

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, dom, dialog

I have a fully ajaxed website, which uses jQuery's $.get calls to fetch the central content of the website upon header clicks.
One of the "screens" (views, actually, using Zend) has a hidden div which is "dialoged" when a user clicks a certain button. This is what happens to me:

1. I get to the desired screen, and click the open dialog button.
2. Dialog opens fine. Closing and reopening works as expected.
3. I go to another screen (mind you, this is ajax, which simply replaces the main content with new content - the hidden div is inside this content, however, and gets replaced along with the main content)
4. I come back to the previous screen (still ajaxing), and click the open dialog button again. Now all of a sudden, there are two of those hidden divs, both with the identical ID (I can see that if I do a console.log($("div#hiddenDiv").length); ) and they are both spawned in dialog form - I have them on top of each other.

The dialogs get duplicated for as many times as I redo this. If I go to another screen, come back, and open dialog again - I get 3, etc.

I took a lot of precautions - I empty the memory at every ajax click, setting all variables I have nothing to do with anymore to null. I also take care to replace the entire content, the hidden divs as well, on every new ajax call, i.e. screen-transition. I checked and made sure that the function which summons the dialog isn't called more than once - it simply dupes the dialog upon returning to the screen which contains it by default, and I have no idea why. Mind you - no other element is duped. Only this hidden soon-to-be-dialog div.

Also worth noting is the fact that the duping process never begins until I open the dialog for the first time. From that moment on, every ajax [departure/return/dialog-opening]-scheme dupes the invisible div.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Edit: Code example:

```
// This causes the screen change when it detects a hash change
// ... stuff ...
if(window.location.hash){
            ajaxData(newhash);
        }
// ... stuff ...


// This causes the actual change of on-screen content (i.e. this is the ajax call) 
function ajaxData(value) {
// ... stuff ...
$.ajax({
    url: "/siteexample/"+value,
    type: "GET",
    mode: "abort",
    dataType: type,
    success: function(data){
        $("#main_content").html(data); // the hidden div is always inside this "data", so it always gets removed when a new screen loads
        loaderdisplay('hide');
        // Clean Memory
        data = null;
    },
    data: ({ajax : 'Y'})
   });
    // ... stuff ....


// And finally, this is the part that summons the dialog
function summonDialog() {
    console.log("here"); // this shows up only once, so I know this function is not called multiple times.
    var dialogBox = $("div#new_window"); // this is the infamous div
    $(dialogBox).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Some title",
        resizable: false,
        zIndex: 22000,
        width: 800,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function(){
                 // some function, ends with:
                 $(dialogBox).dialog("close"); // destroy doesn't change anything
                 dialogBox = null;
            },
            Cancel: function(){
                $(this).dialog("close"); // destroy doesn't change anything
                dialogBox = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So the sequence of events is:
1. ajaxData to the location where the div is.
2. ajaxData away from it.
3. ajaxData back, and open dialog, everything fine.
4. ajaxData away from it.
5. ajaxData back and open dialog, duped.
Rinse and repeat, from now on they're getting duped.

Edit2:
I was able to temporarily hack this into a fix with this in the summonDialog function:

```
var dialogBox = $("div#new_window");
            var usableDialog = dialogBox[0];
            $(dialogBox).remove();
            $(usableDialog).dialog({
// ... dialog code as usual ...
```

But I don't like the solution much. Marc's explanation makes sense, but since I have many different hidden divs with the potential to become dialogs scattered across many different views, removing each one in such a way would be tedious, since they tend to have different context-appropriate IDs and removing by "ui-dialog-content" class (which all divs get once they're dialog-opened) could produce some issues in other parts of the site, since it's a too general scope.

Comment: Can you post a (succinct) example of your code?

Comment: My first inclination is that you're reattaching the `.dialog` to the hidden div. You may want to call `$("selector").dialog("destroy")` before loading the next 'page' content.

Comment: @MArc Tried that, no effect. @Chris Yes, I'll do my best to post something tangible in the next edit.

Comment: @Swader: then perhaps you are duplicating the set-up code on each page for the dialog.

Comment: @Marc: I don't think so, I really am making sure I call everything just once. The div is just.. there, in the phtml, and there's no setup code for it really. Just posted some samples. This is pretty much it, slightly abbreviated though. The div is just a normal hidden div inside that "data" data in the ajaxData function.

Comment: Can you alert the html that comes back from the AJAX call when you believe your dupe is going to appear and see if that has both inside it already? I'm curious to see if it's coming back from the server with the dupe, or it's happening once the DOM is starting to get filled, or after it's been filled.

Comment: @slandau Certainly, just did. It comes back as it should - only one div present in the HTML data that is being returned. It's as if it exits the scope of the main_content, and resides outside it. That would explain why subsequent calls would redraw a clone of the dialog, since only main_content's html is being replaced. But it's nowhere to be seen in the source when I inspect, and there's no reason for that to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the div that is the dialog will be attached and hidden on the body.  Thus, when you replace the `#main_content` html, you're not really removing it.  I would recommend removing the div and re-enabling the `.dialog` plugin on each `html(data)` reload.

Something like this:

```
  success: function(data){
        $("#new_window").remove();            
        $("#main_content").html(data); 
        loaderdisplay('hide');
        summonDialog();
  }
```

And easy way to test this is to simply `console.log($("#new_window").length);` when you get dupes.

Comment: Thanks, good thoughts. I edited my main question accordingly.

Comment: I have decided to re-edit my project in such a manner as to give all dialog-to-be divs a common class. I then updated the ajaxData main function to remove all elements with said class on Success. No need for dialog re-instantiation ot anything else then, tested and everything works fine. Thanks, Marc, you pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad it helped, group debugging to the rescue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, The dialog was duplicated even after

```
$('.content').html('');
```

So I added this:

```
$("#divEditAdvice").remove();
```

That was the solution as @Marc mention above.